# How to prevent title repeating in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have joined two table `images` and `post` tables my script problem when i uploaded two or more images to `image` table `post` table title only one but it repeating images like number i want to know how to fix it anyone can help me thanks my English problem

Post table like this

```
id  title
3   example
```

Images table like this

```
id  img       post_id
1   123.jpg   3
2   22.jpg    3
3   11.jpg    3
4   21.jpg    3
5   34.jpg    3
```

Post title `one` but it repeating 5 `time` images with i want to prevent it

Here is my source code

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("  SELECT p.*,i.img,title,id 
from post AS p LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.post_id= p.id ")) {
$stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<?php echo $row['title']; ?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>"height="20"width="20"/>
<?php
}}
?>
```

Comment: Group by title if added it display only one post

Comment: please try my code.

Comment: is your problem is solved???

Comment: Why did you delete the other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62629036/prevent-title-repeating-join-table-with-in-php-mysqli

Comment: Not solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("  SELECT p.*,i.img,title,id 
from post AS p LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.post_id= p.id ")) {
$stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
$firstTime=true;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<?php 
if($firstTime==true){
echo $row['title'];
$firstTime=false;
}
 ?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>"height="20"width="20"/>
<?php
}}
?>
```

Comment: I checked brother not changing anything

Comment: Please help me bro

Comment: you can use this query: SELECT p.*,i.img
FROM post AS p LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.post_id= p.id WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY p.`title`

Comment: I checked brother same please help me

Comment: My problem, your script solved my all problems thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The column title will be repeated equal to the number of rows returned in the image table, you can not do anything to prevent it.

If you do group by title it will return the number of rows equal to the number of rows in the post table.

But if you elaborate more on what you actually want to do with the result I may help you.

Comment: My problem if there was added 4 images to database after post title repeating 4 time  images table post_id and post table id same i have joined please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Try this please :-**

```
<?php
$a1 = "";
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT p.*,i.img,title,id  
from post AS p INNER JOIN images AS i ON i.post_id=p.id");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows>0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $title = $row['title'];
            $img = $row['img'];
               }
               
 if($a1!= $title){
 $activity="";
 $activity.="<tr>
            <td>$title</td>
            </tr>;
            }
    $activity.="<tr>
            <td><img src="images/<?php echo $img ?>"height="20"width="20"/></td>
                      </tr>";
    $a1=$title; 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Getting same results

Comment: what result you get in `$stmt` after executing queries?